# Return sorted objects of type of a class in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, oop

I have two classes in here where I add the objects of type class Info in a dictionary in the the class Store.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from random import randint
import numpy as np

class Info:
    def __init__(self, grade, age):
        self.grade = grade
        self.age = age

class Store:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = defaultdict(dict)

    def add_obj(self, name, obj):
        self.d[name] = obj

    def return_val(self):
        "return by sorted age desc"
        return self.d

obj = Store()
for _ in range(3):
    name = chr(np.random.randint(ord('a'), ord('z')))
    info = Info(grade = randint(1, 5), age = randint(7, 12))
    obj.add_obj(name, info)

print(obj.return_val())
```

What I am trying to do is to return the created dictionary in the descending order of the age in the return_val method. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Dictionaries are sorted by insertion order. If you want something really sortable, use a list. What output are you expecting, exactly? What have you actually tried? How did it fail?

Comment: No.  A dictionary is stored alphabetically.  A "collections.OrderedDict" is stored in the order they were created.  If you need custom order, pull the keys into a list, sort the list, and return the list and the dict.

Comment: @TimRoberts since Python 3.7+ (and 3.6 as an implementation detail) dict objects maintain insertion order. They have never maintained alphabetic order..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Python 3.7+ you could do:

```
    def return_val(self):
        "return by sorted age desc"
        return dict(
            (key, self.d[key])
            for key in sorted(
                self.d.keys(), key=lambda k: self.d[k].age, reverse=True
            )
        )
```

If not, then use `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
...
    def return_val(self):
        "return by sorted age desc"
        return OrderedDict(...
```

With an `__repr__` addition to the `Info` class

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"(grade={self.grade}, age={self.age})"
```

the output looks like:

```
{'l': (grade=2, age=11), 't': (grade=2, age=8), 'o': (grade=2, age=7)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with the existing code with this, but as others are indicating there are probably better ways to do it.

```py
    def return_val(self):
      return sorted(self.d.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1].age, reverse=True)
```

That will return a list, here's some code to print it with sample output.

```py
for item in obj.return_val():
    print(f'name:{item[0]}, grade:{item[1].grade}, age:{item[1].age}')

"""
name:s, grade:2, age:12
name:x, grade:5, age:10
name:o, grade:5, age:8
"""
```